# Is $2x\geq x$ an axiom?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

From intuition we know $2x\geq x$ is true.

But can we really prove this or is it more of an axiom? If so, does it have a name or more general form?

Comment: It is not true for negative $x$.

Comment: It holds for *natural* numbers; in that case, we can prove it from [axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Probably the question is asked for real numbers.

Comment: @Levent - in that case it is **not** an axiom because it is simply false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$2x\geq x\iff2x-x \ge 0\iff x\ge0$$

More in general for an ordered field $\mathbb{F}$ the following order axioms hold

- $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{F}$ exactly one is true $x>y, x=y, x<y$
- $\forall x,y,z\in \mathbb{F} \quad x<y \quad y<z\implies x<z$
- $\forall x,y,z\in \mathbb{F}\quad x>y \implies x+z>y+z$
- $\forall x,y,z\in \mathbb{F}\quad x>y \quad z>0 \implies xz>yz$

Comment: AFAIK deep in there there is also the axiom that $0 \neq 1$.

Comment: @mike239x I've seen other ways to define them but never this one with for $0\neq 1$ among them

Comment: Well, take a look at your axioms and try proving mine :) But for real, your axioms do not ban the option that all numbers are "equal" to 0.

Comment: @mike239x I've update with a more general case, let me know what your idea about it, thanks.

Comment: Can we maybe have a small discussion in [my chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74198/short-time-room)?

Answer (score 0):

For $x\geq 0$ you have $2x-x=x\geq 0$ hence $2x\geq x$.

Answer (score 0):

When the real numbers are constructed or specified by a set of axioms the assertion
$$
2x > x \text{ for positive } x
$$
 will be a theorem, easily proved from some more general and more useful axioms or theorems.

When you deal with numbers informally, starting in elementary school, it is indeed intuitive, and little more needs to be said,

Comment: Do you mean the axioms specificed by gimusi above?

Comment: @gimusi 's  axiom set is as good as any.